# Help with Taxonomies

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, tags, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a site about London that lists a wide range of attractions. This is the current setup.

I use standard post with categories for attractions, I have also create some custom taxonomies for the following

**Taxonomies**
london_area = This includes areas like Westminster, Covent Garden Etc
underground = This is for underground stations like St James Park, Charing Cross etc.
Each of these has been assigned to the default post type.

With this setup I can display all the attractions that are near each underground station and it is working fine. If I click on the archive I can see all linked articles.

What I would like to do now is add a extra level, each underground station is on a train line, for instance St James park is on the Circle. I would like to link Line>Station>Attraction, meaning that Line is also linked to attraction.

What is the best way to add these lines? I tried setting them up in the following structure. Using a parent taxonomy

**Circle Line**
St James Park
Westminster
Embankment

The issue I face using this approach is that 1 station can only have 1 parent, so St James park cannot be on the Circle Line and the District Line.

Any suggestions on how I can manage this?

Thanks
Richard